# Windows Server 2008 Remote Desktop issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote, desktop

I'm having a strange situation. I have a LAN where I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server and a few other machines (Win 7, Vista). I have configured port forwarding on my router to forward port 4444 to port 3389 on the Server 2008 machine so that I can access it remotely through the router's public IP. I have also set up everything for remote access in the Server 2008 machine (firewall, allow remote assistance, etc).

Now, when I try to remote desktop, I'm able to connect only if I'm on the local subnet (If I'm connected to the router, and I try the public IP:4444, I can RDC). If I try through a different network, the RDC fails. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just forward port 3389 to port 3389?

Comment: If you use the Windows firewall :
Among the "Advanced" tab In the firewall Inbound rules, you have an option "Edge Traversal" : is it set to "Block Edge Traversal" ?

Comment: the different netowrks = different local subnets?

Answer (score 0):

What kind've router/firewall is this?

It sounds like it either:
a)has been limited to internal forwarding only, or
b)something else is screwy.

Also, what kind of client do you have connecting? XP, 7 Vista? Is your RDP Client up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a closer look at the router, if you are able to connect to it at all, and the inbound rules on the firewall.